# Egit リモートアクセス時に「For input string: "268:fd07:4::1"」エラーが発生してしまいます

Tags: git, eclipse, egit

Eclipseを使用してWebシステム開発を行っております。

Egitプラグインを使用してgitサーバーにソースコードを置いて構成管理しています。

２台パソコンがあります。

１台目：マシーン：iMac 27インチ (最新)
OS: Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.2
２台目：マシーン：Mac Book Pro 14インチ(最新)
OS: Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.2

１台目のマシーンではEgitは特に問題なく利用できるのですが、
２台目のマシーンではリモートにpushやリモートからpullするときに以下のエラーが起きて操作することができません。２台目はターミナルからのコマンド操作だとpushやpullができます。

エラー内容

> An internal error occurred during: "Pulling Branch master - project name".
>   For input string: "268:fd07:4::1"

- １台目で問題なく操作できている
- ２台目でコマンド操作だとうまくできている

ことから、２台目のEclipseの環境の問題かと思っておりますが、なかなか解決策が調べてもわかりません。

１台目と２台目の違いとしては１台目は会社にあり、会社のネットワークで接続している。
２台目は自宅にあり、自宅のネットワークで接続している。

すみませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: IPv6 のアドレスの様に見えますね。。`eclipse.ini` に `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` を追加するとどうなりますでしょうか？

Comment: heliac2001さん
ご回答いただきまして、ありがとうございます。
返信がついたことに気づくのが遅くなり申し訳ありません。

アドバイス通りeclipse.iniに１行追加し、かつeclipseをclean実行なども試しましたがエラー内容は変わりませんでした。

Comment: ちなみにeclipseでpullやpushをするとこのような現象が起こるのですが、[プロジェクト]右クリック→[Team]→[Synchronize Workspace]を選択すると[Team Synchroniging]パースペクティブが開かれ、サーバーとの差分を見ることはできます。

Comment: 自己解決しました！ありがとうございました。

以下のサイトを参考にmacの設定でIPV6の設定を切るようにしたらうまくいきました。
http://www.webessentials.biz/osx-customize/ipv6disable/

Comment: 私のコメントはあまり役に立たなかった様で恐縮です(苦笑)。ところで、質問者の方がご自身で解決された場合には、ご自身で回答していただけると助かります。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

[masayukiさんコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6199/#comment6416_6199)：

> 自己解決しました！ありがとうございました。 以下のサイトを参考にmacの設定でIPV6の設定を切るようにしたらうまくいきました。http://webessentials.biz/osx-customize/ipv6disable/